# Как правильно настроить webpack, для работы с pug файлами

Tags: веб-программирование, pug, webpack2

Возникли проблемы с настройкой *webpack*

Надо, чтобы в проекте была динамическая HTML-страница. Лучше, чтобы она пререндерилась на сервере.  Сам фреймворк: *Adonis*, однако стандартный `template language` в нем не такой удобный (`edge` - файлы). Посему решил использовать *Pug*.

Сама структура проекта такая: есть папка `source`, в ней папки для каждой страницы / компонента. После билда *webpack'ом* все попадает в нужные места: 
`public` и `views`.

Все, кроме картинок. Я так и не понял, как по правильному настроить *webpack*, так, чтобы он **не компилировал pug в html** и менял ссылки в `img src` (в случае JPG/JPEG/PNG - это `image/[name].[ext]`, а в случае SVG - `icon/[name].svg`).

И вообще: правильно ли таким образом использовать *pug?*
Или лучше его использовать только во время билда?

Сейчас я использую следующий способ:
Добавляю *pug* файл в *webpack* с помощью: `html-webpack-plugin`, после использую `html-webpack-pug-plugin`, чтобы в файл добавлялись `link` и `script` *pug*-вида.
Я так понимаю, надо настроить `loader`, такая конструкция:

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loaders: ['html-loader', 'pug-html-loader']
}
```

работает, однако на выходе получаю файл с дефолтным HTML шаблоном.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Появилось решение: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-asset-loader
С помощью этого плагина, можно обрабатывать `pug` файлы, используя функцию `pal(<PATH>)` для относительного пути, который будет заменен после сборки.